# in Tkinter i am facing problem of opening extra small blank tk frame

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import RIDGE, Button, Frame, Label, Tk, Toplevel, filedialog, messagebox
import cv2
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import pkg_resources
from main import Face_Recognition_System
import os
import tkinter as tk
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import face_recognition
import mysql.connector


haar=pkg_resources.resource_filename('cv2','data/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

class Flogin:
     
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.face_recog()
        self.video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    
    def face_recog(self):
        self.video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

        def draw_boundray(img, classifier, scaleFactor, minNeighbors, color, text, clf):
            gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            features = classifier.detectMultiScale(gray_image, scaleFactor, minNeighbors)

            coord = []

            for (x, y, w, h) in features:
                cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 3)
                user_name, predict = clf.predict(gray_image[y:y + h, x:x + w])

                confidence = int((100 * (1 - predict / 300)))

                conn = mysql.connector.connect(username='root', password='pass', host='localhost', database='face_recognition', port=3306)
                cursor = conn.cursor()

                cursor.execute("select fname from regteach where user_name=" + str(user_name))
                n = cursor.fetchone()
                n = "+".join(n)

                # cursor.execute("select Roll_No from student where Student_ID=" + str(id))
                # r = cursor.fetchone()
                # r = "+".join(r)

                # cursor.execute("select Student_ID from student where Student_ID=" + str(id))
                # i = cursor.fetchone()
                # i = "+".join(map(str, i))

                # attendance_marked = self.is_attendance_marked(n)  # Check if attendance is already marked

                if confidence > 78:
                    # cv2.putText(img, f"Student_ID:{i}", (x, y - 80), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.8, (64, 15, 223), 2)
                    cv2.putText(img, f"user_name:{n}", (x, y - 55), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.8, (64, 15, 223), 2)
                    # cv2.putText(img, f"Roll-No:{r}", (x, y - 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.8, (64, 15, 223), 2)

                    # if attendance_marked:
                    #     cv2.putText(img, "Already Marked", (x, y - 5), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.8, (255, 0, 0), 2)
                    # else:
                    #     self.mark_attend(i, r, n)
                    
                    self.login()
                    return True
                else:
                    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 3)
                    cv2.putText(img, "Unknown Face", (x, y - 5), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.8, (255, 255, 0), 3)

                # coord = [x, y, w, y]

            return False
        
        

        # # ==========
        # def recognize(img, clf, faceCascade):
        #     coord = draw_boundray(img, faceCascade, 1.1, 10, (255, 25, 255), "Face", clf)
        #     return img

        faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
        clf = cv2.face_LBPHFaceRecognizer.create()
        clf.read("clf_admin.xml")
        videoCap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

        while True:
            ret, img = videoCap.read()
            if draw_boundray(img, faceCascade, 1.1, 10, (255, 25, 255), "Face", clf):
                break
            imgBackground = cv2.imread(r"C:\Users\Bikash\Desktop\Backup\sakib\Python_Test_Project\Images_GUI\facelogin.jpg")
            # Resize imgBackground to match the window size (1366x768)
            imgBackground = cv2.resize(imgBackground, (1366, 768))
            
            # Calculate the position to center the camera frame
            x_offset = (1366 - img.shape[1]) // 2
            y_offset = (768 - img.shape[0]) // 2

            # Overlay the camera frame in the center
            imgBackground[y_offset:y_offset + img.shape[0], x_offset:x_offset + img.shape[1]] = img

            cv2.imshow("Face Detector", imgBackground)
            if cv2.waitKey(1) == 13:
                break


        videoCap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()


    def login(self):
        self.new_window = Toplevel(self.root)
        self.app = Face_Recognition_System(self.new_window)
        self.video_capture.release()  # Release webcam resource

    def on_closing(self):
        self.video_capture.release()  # Release webcam resource
        self.root.distroy()  # Close the window


if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    root = tk.Tk()
    Flogin(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

please solve this:

[image]

Comment: Why are you using duplicate `self.video_capture` you can call self.video_capture anywhere.

Comment: Actually, I do not understand why do you have both `videoCap` and `self.video_capture`?

Comment: Remove duplicate from namespace. import os
import tkinter as tk
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageTk